# Mysql / laravel group query results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am building a laravel 4 based web app that uses a very basic messaging sytem, here is the table structure:

```
messages table
--------------
id int pri
from_user int fk (users table)
to_user int fk (users table)
content text
created_at datetime
updated_at datetime
```

I am trying to retrieve an array containing all messages grouped by messages.from_user and messages.to_user showing the last message sent or received depending upon the scenario.

Here is the code I have been playing with

```
$id = Auth::user()->id; 

$messages = DB::table('messages')
      ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'messages.from_user')
      ->select(
        'users.id AS from_user_id', 
        'users.first_name AS from_user_name',
        'users.profile_img AS from_user_img',
        'users.alias AS from_user_alias'
      )
      ->where('messages.to_user', '=', $id)
      ->groupBy('messages.from_user')
      ->get();

      foreach ($messages as $single) {
            $last = parent::where('messages.to_user', '=', $single->from_user_id)
                ->orWhere('messages.from_user', '=', $single->from_user_id)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->first();
      }

    // return view make with messages
```

This code works okey when a users receive a message but as a sender I wont be able to see the conversation until a get a response.

I am also querying the database for each of the grouped messages, I am not quite sure wether that is going to affect performance or not since I am new to mysql web apps.

Thanks in advance,
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent
```

Try this technique with your message table as you did with parents!